# Is there any way to find freebase data's delta updates?

Tags: freebase

I am currently using freebase data for my application... Want only some information in domains like film, tv, etc. Found out that the tsv dump would be not supported in future and is incomplete. The quad dump has all the information that is needed. The problem is to update the database, the whole dump should be downloaded again and crosschecked with the already downloaded and processed data and then updated. Is there any other way for the data to be updated or to get the delta updates?

Answer (score 1):

You can query the API for things which have changed since the last time that you updated, in the domains that you're interested in, but depending on the quantity of changes you may run into quota issues.

There are no incremental dumps produced, so you'd have generate a diff yourself using two complete dumps, but it would be a straightforward to do particularly since the new RDF dumps appear to be sorted by subject MID unlike the quad dumps.

Answer (score 1):

As Tom points out, the new RDF dumps are sorted by subject which allows you to efficiently diff the whole dataset by iterating through the files. The basic pseudo-code is as follows:

- skip the prefix headers at the start of both files
- while there are lines left in both files:

  - read a line from each file
  - if the subject ID from the old file is greater than the subject ID from new file:

    - read all subsequent lines from the new file with same subject ID
    - add this subject to the list of "added topics"
    - add all lines with this subject to the list of "added facts"
  - else if the subject ID from the old file is less than the subject ID from new file:

    - read all subsequent lines from the old file with same subject ID
    - add this subject to the list of "removed topics"
    - add all lines with this subject to the list of "removed facts"
  - else if subject IDs in both files match:

    - read all subsequent lines from the both file with same subject ID
    - diff the lines to figure out which ones have been added/removed
    - add all added lines to the list of "added facts"
    - add all removed lines to the list of "removed facts"
- output your patch by merging all lists of changes in this order:

  1. removed facts
  2. removed topics
  3. added topics
  4. added facts

This algorithm runs in linear time with very little memory usage so you can easily process multi-gigabyte files on your local machine.

Once you have a diff of the RDF dumps, you need to write some code to apply the patch to your existing database. Because of the way that the patch is ordered, you can always count on topics existing in your database before you try to add or remove facts from them.